Does it matter which holes I use to mount a kitchen faucet?
I am replacing my kitchen faucet. I would like to put a new one where the small faucet is now. Is this possible? I don't need the water filter and the sprayer on the right side.


The "usual" way to do it would be to remove the existing faucet and put the new one in that place. The sink is made for a faucet in that location and the faucets are made to fit in that spot. What is/are the reason(s) for not installing a new faucet in the usual manner?

thanks. Is because the side 'sink' does not get used too much and the filter faucet is right in the center of the bigger sink. But that's fine. I think I'll make my life simple and just replace the old faucet.

I'm not sure. Once you take the old faucet and everything else off, you might get lucky and find that the holes line up in a way that it will work. I doubt it, but good luck.

You can place the new faucet wherever you like. Of course this is dependant on the size of the hole.
The filtered water may have a standard size hole of 1 3/8 to 1 1/2 inches, assuming it wasn't drilled specifically for the fixture. That size will accommodate most all faucets. You will know after disassembly.  If the hole is too small, you could drill it larger with a stepped drill.
Any unused holes can be plugged with a sink hole cover.

Could work.  Note that the filter hole appears to be offset from the faucet and sprayer holes, which may or may not affect working room underneath.

Not only does a faucet not care where you plant it, you can modify holes as needed. I added a second soap dispenser (hand soap, dish detergent) to my stainless sink by punching out a new opening.
As long as it physically fits (above and below), and there's room for normal operation, do whatever you like.

There are either 3 or 5 holes in the back of your sink. If your new faucet needs only one, you can use any one.  You will have to buy filler discs for the rest.
Many one-hole faucets come with a cover for a three-hole sink.   Just like the one you have there now.    If you buy a one-hole faucet, you may like the look of its cover better than having 4 filler disks.  In that case, you can install it in the same place as the old one, and you MIGHT be able to install it one hole to the right if the old sprayer hole remained underneath it.
You can use any of the old holes for a soap or lotion dispenser instead of a cover.
If you buy a faucet with an integrated sprayer, it will have a hose with  weight on it.   You have to make sure the area directly beneath it is free of obstructions for that.
